# Script loading failure from googletagmanager

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

So I added google analytics to my site, and the code snippet that google gave me was this:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-124075233-1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-124075233-1');
</script>
```

So I added it to my `<head>`, but now I'm receiving the error:

> Loading failed for the  with source
> “https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-124075233-1”.

I'm a bit confused as to why this is happening.

Comment: It works fine for me on your website. Can you check if you have any adblocker installed which prevents GA ?

Comment: Still getting the error in firefox. Chrome gives me an error as well, but only on refresh.

Comment: I checked on Firefox, and still works ok for me! no error at all. Check for Ad blockers and your browser updates

Comment: I had same problem. and solved with @zacaway's answer. My problem caused by adguard!

Comment: I did not resolve this, but instead I commented out`firebase.analytics()` and this error went away. Since i wasn't using analytics anyways so that's not a problem for me.

Comment: Also note that this error will not interfare with your program, even though it can be a little bit annoying. I was using incorrect call so this error had nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I had the same problem.  It turned out to be the DuckDuckGo Privacy Essentials browser extension that I was using was blocking the Google tracker request.  Just disabling this extension for the site resolved the problem.

I suggest checking to see if you have a similar browser extension that is blocking the request.

Comment: If you are testing using a Brave browser, click on the lion-shield and disable the protection

Comment: I can add that ublock blocks the gtag script... Thanks for reminding me extensions can f with development... -_-

Comment: I had the exact same problem with the DuckDuckGo browser

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but basically it's just because you're using a tracker blocker (like Ghostery).
If you're using one, you will probably see this message in more than just your website.
Try to whitelist your site and see if it works well

Answer (score 0):

Please check your code, where do you put that code? are you using cms like WordPress? it's possible you put in the wrong place, for example, you put that code between `<?php` tag

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to check is your adblocker. I used v2rayn for my proxy and blocked some ad sites, and somehow googletagmanager.com was one of them.